# Equivalence of possible definitions of quasi-coherent sheaves on a prescheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

this is my first question on stackexchange. So, please don't be too hard to me. I am listening to a master course in Algebraic Geometry.

My question belongs to Proposition II.5.4 in Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry". I want to show that the following statements are equivalent:

**Proposition**:

Let $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ be a prescheme and $\mathcal{F}$ be an 
$\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Then the following statements are equivalent:

1) For all open affine $U \subseteq X$ there is an $\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_X)$-module M, sucht that $F_{|U} \cong \tilde{M}$.

2) There is an open affine covering $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $X$ and some $\Gamma(U_i, \mathcal{O}_X)$-modules $M_i$, such that $\mathcal{F}_{|U_i} \cong \tilde{M_i}$.}

The implication from 1) to 2) is clear. To prove the other direction, I oriented at the proof of Hartshorne. I hope, you can fill the gaps:

First, I proved the following lemma:

**Lemma**:

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $\mathcal{F}=\tilde{M}$. Then $\mathcal{F}_{|D(f)} \cong \tilde{M_f}$ for any $f \in R$.

**Proof of the proposition**:

Let $U =SpecR \subseteq X$ be open and affine. Assume, the second statement holds. We denote the corresponding ring of $U_i$ by $R_i$. Then  $\{U \cap U_i\}_{i \in I}$ is an open, not necessarily affine covering of $U$.

Step 1: We want to show, that $\mathcal{F}{|U}$ satisfies the second statement.

Since $U \cap U_i \subseteq U_i$ is open,

\begin{align*}
U \cap U_i = \bigcup_{j \in J_i} D(g_{ij})
\end{align*}

for some $g_{ij} \in R_i$.

Therefore, $\{D(g_{ij}) ~|~ i \in I, j \in J_i\}$ is an open affine coveriung of $U$. Using the lemma and the assumption, we have:

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}_{|D(g_{ij})} = {\mathcal{F}_{|U_i}}_{|D(g_{ij})} \cong \widetilde{{(M_i)}_{g_{ij}}}
\end{align*}

Step 2: We want to finish the proof.

We define $M = \Gamma(U, \mathcal{F}_{|U})$. So we have the identity map

\begin{align*}
M \to \Gamma(U, \mathcal{F}_{|U}).
\end{align*}

Since $\widetilde{}$ and $\Gamma$ are adjoint functors, this leads to a map
\begin{align*}
\alpha \colon \tilde{M} \to \mathcal{F}_{|U}.
\end{align*}

Now, I want to use that $\alpha_{|D(g_{ij})}$ is the isomorphism, which we received in step 1. Because then, since the $D(g_{ij})$'s are an open covering, $\alpha$ has to be an isomorphism.

But why is this the case?

Thank you in advance for your help. And please tell me, if I am abusing notation. I want to be as formal as possible.

Felix

Comment: I think you can use the Affine Communication Lemma to prove (2) implies (1). It is Lemma 5.3.2 in Vakil's text, available here: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf .